# CAML RenderPattern Get current list Item ID

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, caml, caml-renderpattern

In a my share point 2007 list i have a custom field. In the custom field  i need to get the current Item ID. Later have to pass this to a JavaScript. How to get the current Item ID in RenderPattern ?

I used to get this in XSLT rendering using `$thisNode/@ID`. NOt in the CAML RenderPattern

Is there a way to set item id value to a variable using CAML `<SetVar>` and access using `<GetVar>` ?

Capturing the counter as below, doesn't seem to work as it gives the index not the item id. Basically i need to capture item id as it can then be used to identify the item and could be passed to a WebMethod for processing.

```
<SetVar Name="counter">
  <Counter />
</SetVar>
```

How can this be done within `<RenderPattern>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Solution 
`<ID />` works